# What's the shortest time to reflight of a Falcon 9 booster?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse

What has been the shortest time in between the landing of a Falcon 9 booster, and SpaceX reusing them on a different mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia page detailing the individual boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_first-stage_boosters#Booster_turnaround_time), the shortest turnaround thus far is booster B1045, launching TESS on 18 April 2018 and CRS-15 on 29 June 2018 - 2 months 11 days.